# Grpc.Auth: Could not load type 'Grpc.Core.CallCredentials' from assembly 'Grpc.Core.Api'

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, google-cloud-platform, grpc

### Context

I'm trying to use Google's Cloud Natural Language API. I have my service account key JSON file, and am trying to write a simple .NET Core application (more specifically an Azure Function using .NET Core) that will take in some text and use the sentiment analysis function from the Natural Language API and return a couple values.

I'm basing my implementation off Google's documentation, specifically the code section under the heading:

[Passing the path to the service account key in code](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually)

The following is my application:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Google.Cloud.Language.V1;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Grpc.Auth;

namespace Project.Function
{
    public static class GoogleNLAPI
    {
        [FunctionName("GoogleNLAPI")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Admin, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log,
            ExecutionContext context)
        {
            string content = req.Query["content"];

            var path = Path.Combine(context.FunctionAppDirectory, "{FILE-NAME}");
            var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(path)
                .CreateScoped(LanguageServiceClient.DefaultScopes);
            var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(
                LanguageServiceClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(),
                credential.ToChannelCredentials()
            );
            var languageClient = LanguageServiceClient.Create(channel);
            var response = languageClient.AnalyzeSentiment(new Document()
            {
                Content = content,
                Type = Document.Types.Type.PlainText
            });
            var sentiment = response.DocumentSentiment;

            return new OkObjectResult($"Score: {sentiment.Score}\nMagnitude: {sentiment.Magnitude}");
        }
    }
}
```

And the .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>google_nl_api</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.28"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.Language.V1" Version="1.2.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Auth" Version="1.40.2"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Auth" Version="1.21.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="{FILE-NAME}">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

### Issue

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Exception while executing function: GoogleNLAPI. Grpc.Auth: Could not load type 'Grpc.Core.CallCredentials' from assembly 'Grpc.Core.Api, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d754f35622e28bad'.
```

I'm using Grpc.Auth because without it I am unable to use `.ToChannelCredentials()`, which seems to be the method where the error is occurring.

Comment: Out of interest, have you seen this in deployment as well, or just in the emulator? I've only looked at it in the context of the emulator, and it would be nice to know whether this affects real deployments... although understandably not being able to use the emulator may be too much of a blocker anyway.

Comment: Use version 1.3.0 from Google.Cloud.Vision. It depends on Grpc.Core (>= 1.18.0) which is good for azure functions. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1/1.3.0

Comment: Good call @OscarFraxedas I am using the Google.Cloud.Language.V1 package. I found the newest version (1.2.0) that depends on Grpc.Core (>= 1.18.0) and that fixed my problem in Azure Functions Emulator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> more specifically an Azure Function using .NET Core

That's the problem, unfortunately.

At least in the *emulator*, there's a problem where the emulator contains an older version of Grpc.Core than 1.21.0. Normally that would only be a problem if new features were being used, but around 1.19.0 (IIRC), Grpc.Core was split into Grpc.Core and Grpc.Core.Api, with type forwarding handling the compatibility issue. That's fine until you use code that *expects* the split to be present, but finds that the old version of Grpc.Core has been loaded instead.

This [issue has been reported to Microsoft](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4527) but I haven't seen any workarounds yet. Note that you don't even need any direct reference to `Google.Apis.Auth` or `Grpc.Auth` - see the repro I posted in the final comment on that issue.

Comment: I changed Grpc.Auth version to 1.19.0 and that resolved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answer from @JonSkeet the link (https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4527) provides a work around to add the following lines to the Azure Function .csproj file that will resolve the immediate issue:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
   <!--https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3568-->
   <!--<Exec Command="copy $(OutDir)bin\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Private.ServiceModel.dll $(OutDir)bin\System.Private.ServiceModel.dll" />-->
   <Exec Command="copy $(OutDir)$(ProjectName).deps.json $(OutDir)bin\function.deps.json" />
 </Target>
 <Target Name="PostPublish" BeforeTargets="AfterPublish">
   <!--https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3568-->
   <!--<Exec Command="copy $(PublishDir)bin\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Private.ServiceModel.dll $(PublishDir)bin\System.Private.ServiceModel.dll" />-->
   <Exec Command="copy $(PublishDir)$(ProjectName).deps.json $(PublishDir)bin\function.deps.json" />
 </Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I had to upgrade my package

```
"Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.29" -> "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.31"
```