# Using Firestore with Azure Functions V2 (C#)

Tags: c#, firebase, azure, google-cloud-firestore, google-authentication

I am trying to use Firestore with Azure Functions, but I'm getting the following error:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function:
>   HelloWorld. Grpc.Auth: Could not load type 'Grpc.Core.CallCredentials'
>   from assembly 'Grpc.Core.Api, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=d754f35622e28bad'.

I tried to use the steps from this question:

[Grpc.Auth: Could not load type 'Grpc.Core.CallCredentials' from assembly 'Grpc.Core.Api'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56708920/grpc-auth-could-not-load-type-grpc-core-callcredentials-from-assembly-grpc-c)

however, it's related to the Language APIs, and the solution doesn't work for Firestore.

I tried changing the version of `Grpc.Auth` to 1.19.0, but this version doesn't appear to be supported by Firestore 1.0.0.

If I remove Firestore from the project and use `grps.Auth` 1.19.0 to initialize the Credentials object - this works. But the object isn't compatible with Firestore.

I also tried the `PostBuild`/`PostPublish` commands described in that question, but the commands fail to execute.

Before trying to use Firestore with Azure Functions, I successfully managed to use it with a .NET Core Web API project, but I'm struggling with Azure Functions and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try to update Grpc.Auth to latest?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is a bug  in Azure Functions and you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/issues/3101) to track it.

If you [update the cli directory](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4527) to contain the relevant files from `Grpc.Core` and `Grpc.Core.Api`, and update `func.deps.json` accordingly, it all works - including `Google.Cloud.Firestore`.

So basically, this is a problem for any function needing to use a version of `Grpc.Core` later than the one embedded in the CLI application.